# React Transition Group: What is the difference between the appear, enter, exit events and the enter, active done className suffixes?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

Why are there so many variations? I recorded my developer tools' elements tab and it appears only the "-enter-done" and "-exit" classes are being applied to the elements being animated.

Answer (score 6):

The docs [explain it](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) pretty easily:

> CSSTransition applies a pair of class names during the appear, enter,
> and exit stages of the transition. The first class is applied and then
> a second "active" class in order to activate the css animation. After
> the animation, matching done class names are applied to persist the
> animation state.

So appear, enter and exit are different situations when these animations are triggered.

**Appear** - when you want transition on component first mount (like when you refresh a page).

**Enter** - transition when a new element has mounted.

**Exit** - when element un-mounts.

The role of suffixes is to allow you set different CSS property at each step of animation.

```
.my-animation-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.my-animation-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.my-animation-enter-done {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working example? In my project, some of the suffixes are never applied such as -exit-done